# Declare DateTime variable in cshtml

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to declare DateTime FromDate and ToDate in cshtml and assigning them when the Model is not null.

```
@{       
DateTime FromDate;
DateTime ToDate;    

if (Model != null)
{
    FromDate = ViewBag.fromDate;
    ToDate = ViewBag.toDate;        
}}
```

I tried to declare the DateTime variables in these ways, but am getting the error which says, "Use of Unassigned local variable"

```
DateTime FromDate = string.Empty; DateTime FromDate= Convert.ToDateTime(string.Empty);
```

can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from the fact that `if Model == null` your `FromDate` and `ToDate`s would never be assigned values.

All code paths must provide `FromDate` and `ToDate` a value - because of this your best bet is to initialize the variables with values, even if it's something arbitrary:

```
DateTime FromDate = new DateTime(); // instantiated as 0001/01/01
DateTime ToDate = new DateTime(); // instantiated as 0001/01/01
```

you will no longer receive the error `Use of Unassigned local variable` when declared like this, as the `DateTime`s will always have a value, regardless of the state of `Model`.

You can see the difference between both approaches [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlPGp3).  Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program.DateTimeWithoutValue();
        Program.DateTimeWithValue();
    }

    public static void DateTimeWithValue()
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();

        var i = 1;

        if (i != 1)
            startDate = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine(startDate); // valid  
    }

    public static void DateTimeWithoutValue()
    {
        DateTime startDate;

        var i = 1;

        if (i != 1)
            startDate = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine(startDate); // use of unassigned local variable error 
    }   
}
```